# File output to hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I'm making a program that will put a comment with my name, the date, the name of the file, and the description of what it does. It also looks for any `int` and `void` functions that adds a description of what each function does. 
**I've already done these steps!**

I created a `vector<string>` which reads the whole file into itself. Then it searches for any `void` or `int` functions that is within the vector. If it finds a `int` it calls `string findParameters` to find the parameters of the int and lists them within the description.

***Example:***

```
/*THE DESCRIPTION THAT THE PROGRAM MADE IS BELLOW*/

/*Function: int nDigits
Description: 
     Description of the function
Parameters:
     long long number: Description
 Returns:
     returnVal: Description
*/

/*THE FUNCTION THE PROGRAM WAS LOOKING FOR IS BELLOW*/
int nDigits(long long number){


    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; number > 0; counter++){
        number = number / 10;

    }

    return counter;

}
```

***Problem***

The program runs fine when it doesn't exceed 160 lines, but anything over it will convert everything into hexadecimal when I output and when I try to open it in notepad most of my code is deleted besides the last few functions.

***Example of File Output***

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0020 2020 2020 200d 0a20 2020 2020
2020 2063 6f75 6e74 6572 2b2b 3b0d 0a20
2020 2020 2020 2066 616b 655f 6e75 6d62
6572 202f 3d20 3130 3b0d 0a20 2020 207d
0d0a 2020 2020 0d0a 2020 2020 0d0a 2020
```

Of course there is about 400 lines of this.

I have no idea what's going on so any help would be very appreciated! I believe it might be limitations onto how many lines I'm putting into my vector?

***My Code***

***Finding Parameters Function***

```
string findParameters(string line, string outputFileName, vector<string> &list_parameters){


    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(outputFileName, ios::out);
    int comma;
    string something;
    int length;
    int parstart;
    int parend;
    int last;
    if (outFile.is_open()) {

        if (line.find("(") != string::npos) {
            last = parstart = line.find("(",0) + 1;

            if (line.find(")", parstart + 1) != string::npos) {
                 parend = line.find(")", parstart + 1) + 1;



                    do {
                        comma = line.find(",", last+1);

                        if (comma == string::npos) {
                            length = parend - last;
                            something = line.substr(last, length-1);

                            list_parameters.push_back("\n     " + something);
                        }
                        else {
                            length = comma - last;
                            something = line.substr(last, length);

                            list_parameters.push_back("\n     " + something);
                            last = comma+1;
                        }
                    } while (comma != string::npos);




            }
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nfile find parameters did not open";
    }

    return "";

}
```

***Outputing Header Function***

```
    //Starting Header
        //File Name
    outFile << "/* \nFilename: " << outputFileName;

        //Date
    char date[9];
    _strdate_s(date);
    outFile << "\n\nDate: " << date << "\n";
        //Description
    outFile << "\nProgrammer: Dyrenex\n\nDescription:\n     //Description of what the code in the file is meant to do and how it does what it is meant to do" << "\n";
    outFile << "\n\n */ \n\n";



    size_t found;
    //Writing the Rest of Input File
    while (isDone != existingFile.size()){

        //Finding void functions
        line = existingFile[isDone];
        if (line.find("void") != string::npos){
            //cout << "\nFound a void!" << "\n";
            outFile << "\n/*Function: \nDescription:\n     Description of the function\nParameters:" <<
                "\n     Parameters here\n Returns:\n     returnVal:*/";

        }
        else if (line.find("int",0) != string::npos) {
            int intstart = line.find("int");

            if (line.find("(", intstart + 1) != string::npos) {
                int parstart = line.find("(", intstart + 1);

                if (line.find(")", parstart + 1) != string::npos) {
                    int parend = line.find(")", parstart + 1);
                    vector<string> list_parameters;

                    outFile << "\n/*Function: " << line.substr(intstart, parstart)
                        << "\nDescription: \n     Description of the function\nParameters:";

                    findParameters(line, outputFileName,list_parameters);

                    int counter = 0;

                    while (counter != list_parameters.size()) {
                        outFile << list_parameters[counter] << ": Description";
                        counter++;
                    }


                        outFile << "\n Returns:\n     returnVal: Description\n*/";

                }
            }
        }

        //outputting file line
        outFile << "\n" << existingFile[isDone];

        isDone++;

    }


    outFile.close();
```

***Reading Existing File***

```
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(inputFileName, ios::in);
    if (inFile.is_open()){

        while (!inFile.eof()){

            getline(inFile, line);
            existingFile.push_back(line);
        }

        inFile.close();
     }
```

***This is not my homework! I'm doing this as a side project to automate putting my name on my homework so I don't have to do it for every assignment! ***

Thank you so much in advance!

I tried to put the headers to make my code neat into my question but if you don't like the format of my question ***here's a link to all my code*** http://pastebin.com/4P5hFzQm

***Bellow is the .cpp(The input file) that I'm trying to manipulate***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int nDigits(long long number){


    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; number > 0; counter++){
        number = number / 10;

    }

    return counter;

}

int reverse(long long number){

    int reverse = 0;
    while (number > 0){

        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;

    }

    return reverse;
}

bool isPalindrome(long long number){

    if (number == reverse(number)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool repeatsDigit (long long number){


    int temp[1024];
    long long fake_number = number;
    int counter = 0;
    int limit = nDigits(number);


    while (fake_number > 0){
        temp[counter] = fake_number % 10;

        counter++;
        fake_number /= 10;
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++){

        for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < limit; counter2++){

            if (temp[counter] == temp[counter2] && counter != counter2){
                return true;
            }

        }

    }

    return false;
}

void digitCount( long long n, int& eCount, int& oCount){

    int temp[1024];
    long long fake_number = n;
    int counter = 0;
    int limit = nDigits(n);


    while (fake_number > 0){
        temp[counter] = fake_number % 10;

        counter++;
        fake_number /= 10;
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++){

        if (temp[counter] % 2 == 0){
            eCount++;
        }
        else{
            oCount++;
        }

    }


}

int largest(long long n){

    int temp[1024];
    long long fake_number = n;
    int counter = 0;
    int limit = nDigits(n);
    int largestnum = 0;

    while (fake_number > 0){
        temp[counter] = fake_number % 10;

        counter++;
        fake_number /= 10;
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++){

        if (largestnum < temp[counter]){
            largestnum = temp[counter];
        }

    }
    return largestnum;
}
int smallest(long long n){

    int temp[1024];
    long long fake_number = n;
    int counter = 0;
    int limit = nDigits(n);
    int smallestnum = 10;

    while (fake_number > 0){
        temp[counter] = fake_number % 10;

        counter++;
        fake_number /= 10;
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++){

        if (smallestnum > temp[counter]){
            smallestnum = temp[counter];
        }

    }

    return smallestnum;
}
double average(long long n){

    int temp[1024];
    long long fake_number = n;
    int counter = 0;
        int limit = nDigits(n);
        double averagenum = 0;

    while (fake_number > 0){
        temp[counter] = fake_number % 10;

        counter++;
        fake_number /= 10;
    }


    for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++){

        averagenum += temp[counter];

    }

    return averagenum/nDigits(n);
}


int main(){

    long long something = 12345;
    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount = 0;



    /*real output*/
    ifstream file;
    file.open("integers.dat",ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()){
        file >> something;
        cout << "The number of digits in " << something << " is " << nDigits(something) << "\n";

        file >> something;
        cout << "The reverse of : " << something << " is " << reverse(something) << "\n";

        file >> something;
        if (isPalindrome(something) == 1){
            cout << "There is a Palindrome in number: " << something << "\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << something << " is NOT a Palindrome" << "\n";

        }

        file >> something;
        if (repeatsDigit(something) == 1){
            cout << "There are repeat digits in " << something << "\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << "There are NOT repeat digits: in " << something << "\n";

        }
        file >> something;
        digitCount(something, evenCount, oddCount);
        cout << "There are " << evenCount <<" Even and, " << oddCount <<" Odd in the number " << something << "\n";

        file >> something;
        cout << "The largest Number in " << something << " is " << largest(something) << "\n";

        file >> something;
        cout << "The smallest Number in " << something << " is " << smallest(something) << "\n";

        file >> something;
        cout << "The average Number in " << something << " is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << average(something) << "\n";

    }
    else {
        cout << "File did not open";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***Also the output file is a new file that the program is naming so name it whatever you want...It doesn't really matter***

Again thank you, and if you have any questions please ask! I'm trying to learn as much as I can and this site is helping me do that too!

Comment: That's a lot of code for an SO question.

Comment: @RSahu I just cut it down. Is it better? I put a pastebin just incase you want to see all the code. Also the last block of code is the input file so you can just ignore everything in it since it's just going to be inputted as a string into the vector.

Comment: You are clearly trying hard to give a lot of information to reduce chances of negative comments here. I applaud the effort. However, (and please do not be discouraged by this, I am trying to be helpful), you did not give any description of any efforts you've made to figure out the source of this issue. For example, if you have access to a debugger, run the program through it and see what happens when you reach the 160 line threshold. Think about what should be in different variables, then look at what they actually contain. Try to explain the differences and you might have the answer.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment: There is a lot of code here with little information on what you have or have not tried to fix it. So you are expecting someone else to go through the whole thing and figure it out for you. Instead, analyse the code in pieces and figure out what is clearly working. Then eliminate (delete) the working code and create a smaller sample code that has the problem. Keep doing this till you get to a minimal example that shows the problem. At that stage, if you still do not see why it is doing this (I bet you will), post that minimal code. You might get better responses.

Comment: @crayzeewulf No problem! I really love this community and just recently began to be more interactive. I will go back now and use the debugger! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Dyrenex, I don't know how to help. It's a lot of code. It doesn't fit the criteria of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @crayzeewulf Honestly your comment inspired me to look even deeper for the problem! Thank you! I will definitely use the debugger and analyze the code in smaller chunks. I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @RSahu I will work on that for future questions! I'm am sorry for any trouble!

Comment: @Dyrenex It is not an inconvenience at all. I am trying to describe a process of debugging that has helped me a lot and in the process has help me learn more. It is a lot more valuable than just giving you the answer to the problem, IMHO. Hopefully, you will have the same experience. Cheers, and hope you find the solution to this problem very soon. The link that RSahu posted is very useful read too.

Comment: @Dyrenex, no worries. Good luck with your debugging effort.

Comment: `findParameters` opens the output file for writing, which truncates it. It does this every time you call it. Why does it open a file?

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh wow! I had class so I wasn't in front of a computer, but I never noticed this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow through your code but it doesn't look like it is doing much with the vector, it's just storing it. If I am not mistaken you can make your program a lot shorter like the code below.

However to properly identify a function you do need a need to store the lines in vector to examine it.

```
int main() 
{
    const char* note = "Etcetera Etcetera";

    ifstream in("in.cpp");
    ofstream out("out.cpp");

    string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        if (
                (
                    line.find('(') != string::npos && 
                    line.find(')') != string::npos
                ) 
                &&
                (
                    line.find("double") == 0 ||
                    line.find("int") == 0 ||
                    line.find("bool") == 0 ||
                    line.find("void") == 0
                )
            )
        {
            out << note << endl;
        }

        out << line << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is very helpful! Thank you. I'll implement this into my program. Every time I look at other people's code I feel like I have a lot to learn haha!

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I skipped error checks on files, remember to put that back.